# Optimization using gcc flags

Tags: gcc, optimization, flags

I am new to C and I am trying to optimize my code for matrix multiplication. I am trying to use the gcc optimization flags but cannot figure out the syntax. Can anyone help?

```
gcc       -O2          -funroll-loops -dgemm-blocked.c
    Optimization Level    flag name       file name
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You don't put a hyphen before the file name.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. What exactly is your problem?  I can see one — I've no idea what the `-d` flag is for, but it probably isn't doing what you want.  Your file name should be separate from other option arguments (`-d gemm-blocked.c`).  Or, if your file name really begins with a dash, then you are in for a world of pain and will have to use `./-dgemm-blocked.c` as the file name. What effects are you seeing?  What effects are you not seeing that you wanted to see?  Is the compiler complaining?  If so, what does it say?

Comment: The `d` is most likely part of the file name, as `DGEMM` is one of the core BLAS functions.

Comment: @user2357112: OK; that makes sense.  And in that case, your initial advice (no hyphen before file name) makes more sense.  And the command line is probably missing a `-lblas` or something similar to link the BLAS library and possibly (before that) a `-L/usr/local/blas/lib` or something similar to specify the directory where the BLAS library is found.

Comment: the file name is dgemm-blocked.c I have removed the - before the file name still the compiler is not accepting the flag.                                          I am getting the following error. expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘-’ token

Comment: Can anyone refer me a good source for getting started with SSE